# Canceling Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm facing an issue with canceling my Asynctask..

I think my problem could be simple but i can't figure out how to code it.

I use

`while( !isCancelled() )`

in my doinbackground but the problem is that the asynctask never loads on post execute and the only way to interrupt it is to press the cancel button on my Progress Dialog.

I need to if i press the cancel button to cancel the asynctask and if i didn't press cancel it should act normally (where the !isCancelled() check is never triggered )

so it never ends normally.

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array

        while( !isCancelled() )
        {

            UsersPostsGet = new ArrayList<UsersPostsGet>();
            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        mainroadfrom.replace(" ", "")
                                + mainroadto.replace(" ", ""));
                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending
                //

                Date midnight = new Date();
                midnight.setHours(0);
                midnight.setMinutes(0);
                midnight.setSeconds(0);

                Date elevenfiftynine = new Date();
                elevenfiftynine.setHours(23);
                elevenfiftynine.setMinutes(59);
                elevenfiftynine.setSeconds(59);

                query.whereGreaterThan("createdAt", midnight);
                query.whereLessThan("createdAt", elevenfiftynine);
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

                Time dtNow = new Time();
                dtNow.setToNow();

                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {

                    int hoursnow = new Date().getHours();
                    int minsnow = new Date().getMinutes();

                    int sumnow = hoursnow * 60 + minsnow;

                    int hourspost = country.getCreatedAt().getHours();
                    int minspost = country.getCreatedAt().getMinutes();

                    int sumpost = hourspost * 60 + minspost;

                    int total = sumnow - sumpost;

                    int i = total / 60;
                    int j = total % 60;

                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (j <= 1) {
                            x = j + " Minute";
                        }

                        else {
                            x = j + " Minutes";
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        if (j <= 1) {
                            x = i + " Hour " + j + " Minute";
                        }

                        else {
                            x = i + " Hours " + j + " Minutes";
                        }
                    }

                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("imageattach");

                    UsersPostsGet map = new UsersPostsGet();
                    map.setUsername((String) country.get("username"));
                    map.setUserpost((String) country.get("userpost"));
                    map.setId((String) country.getObjectId());
                    map.setStatus((String) country.get("status"));
                    map.setReport((String) country.get("report"));
                    map.setDisplayname((String) country.get("displayname"));

                    map.setPosttime(x);

                    if (image == null) {
                        map.seturl("");
                    }

                    else {
                        map.seturl(image.getUrl());
                    }

                    map.setIdpost(mainroadfrom.replace(" ", "")
                            + mainroadto.replace(" ", ""));

                    UsersPostsGet.add(map);


                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

        return null;
    }
```

my cancel code

```
mProgressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                         RemoteDataTask.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I've added it to the post...my problem is that my asynctask never finishes normally to my on post execute and i have to press the cancel button in my Alert Dialog to cancel it.

Comment: You should also include the `isCancelled()` code, to see how are you handling the cancellation of that loop.

Comment: added code to my question

Comment: a good example on correct way to cancel and asynctask in android http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Comment: a good example on correct way to cancel and asynctask in android http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your code within a loop that returns a `boolean` value, but it only returns `true` (and therefore you exit the loop) if you cancel the `AsyncTask`. I think what you're trying to achieve is similar to this, but assuming *you* want to control when to exit. So, you should define your own `boolean` value class-wide, for instance, define:

```
boolean dontExit = true;
```

Then change your loop to:

```
while (!dontExit) {
  // Your code
  ...
}
```

Somewhere within your code, there must be some condition to make that `dontExit` value as false, so you have to implement some logic inside the loop do determine **when** to exit. For instance:

```
if (number_of_loop_processing > 200)
  dontExit = false;
```

This would make your loop end and go to the `onPostExecute()` code.

The difference is that now, the `isCancelled()` is called when, as its name denotes, the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` is completely cancelled so it exits and jumps to the `onCancelled()` event, but this happens just then, when you cancel it so you cannot add your own logic to it.

Comment: I will try to implement this way and see if it works..Thanks for your help!

Comment: **"completely cancelled so it exits and jumps to the onPostExecute()"** - If an 'AsyncTask' is cancelled `onPostExecute(...)` is never called - instead `onCancelled(...)` is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `cancel` method, the `onCancelled` method of your `AsyncTask` is executed, so that's how you can distinguish what happened. Keep a reference to your `AsyncTask` and call its cancel method when the button on the dialog is pressed and that should do the trick.

From the documentation:

A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: Thanks Ameen. my problem is that my asynctask never finishes normally to on post execute and i have to press the cancel button in my Alert Dialog to cancel it (to make the while check true).